# Restart Terminal in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, nvm

Installed `nvm` and you have to close and reopen terminal to start using it. How would I do this for a Github Action workflow.

Comment: Why do you have to restart the terminal? To source shell startup files? And that, why? For environment variables to come into effect?

Comment: Can you avoid using `nvm` with the [`setup-node` action](https://github.com/actions/setup-node)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script):

> On Linux, after running the install script, if you get nvm: command
> not found or see no feedback from your terminal after you type command
> -v nvm, simply close your current terminal, open a new terminal, and try verifying again. **Alternatively, you can** run the following commands
> for the different shells on the command line:
>
> bash: source ~/.bashrc
>
> zsh: source ~/.zshrc
>
> ksh: . ~/.profile

To answer your question, you just have to run the right startup file depending on the shell you use.